# Flutter: CMake Error at flutter/CMakeLists.txt:75 (add_custom_command): This character is not allowed

Tags: flutter, cmake, flutter-linux

I created a flutter project recently but when I try to run it shows me the error below, how to solve it? Thanks in advance!

`**CMake Error at flutter/CMakeLists.txt:75 (add_custom_command): add_custom_command called with OUTPUT containing a "#".  This character is not allowed. Exception: Unable to generate build files**`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that there's no # character in any of the directories in your path to where the Flutter project is located. For example, if you have path like this;

C:\#projects#flutter\your_project

You need to remove all hashtags # present, you will have something like this

C:\projects\flutter\your_project

Hope it helped you out ^_^